# API design and security when dealing with AJAX

Tags: security, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm beginning to build out an API using .NET Web API.  I'm coming across scenarios where I need to think about how to prevent abuse of my API.  Take this example:

On my account creation form, I have a client-side check to see if the username is taken.  This check is something like this:

```
var exists = false;

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/people?username=' + name,
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
        exists = response;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert('error');
    }
});

return exists;
```

My ultimate question is: how do best secure my API so that someone can't build something that just pings https://example.com/api/people?username=blah looking for info?  I've read about adding Basic Auth, but how is that design best implemented in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using Access Control rules and only allow calls from www.example.com, so if someone calls from www.othersite.com, it will reject the request.

[Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

[Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

But if you're trying to allow outside sites to access your API, you will definitely need authentication. Hope this helps!!